Why do nusach sefard/ sefardim interrupt kaddish with a seemingly unnecessary amen?
Nusach sefard, sefardim and maybe others have the following nusach for Kaddish:

יתגדל ויתקדש שמה רבא (אמן) בעלמא די ברא כרעותה וימליך מלכותה ויצמח פורקנה ויקרב משיחה  (אמן) בחייכון וביומיכון ובחיי דכל בית ישראל בעגלא ובזמן קריב ואמרו אמן (אמן)...
Exalted and sanctified be His great name (Amen) in the world which He created according to His will and may He rule His kingdom bring forth His redemption and hasten the coming of His Mashiach (Amen) In your lifetime and in your days, and in the lifetime of the entire House of Israel, speedily and in the near future - and say amen (Amen)... (Translation by sefaria)

Why does the second Amen, (which nusach Ashkenaz completely omits, along with the previous few words) interrupt the sentence which wishes for Hashem's kingdom etc. to come within our lifetimes, instead of 'relying' on the Amen at the end of the sentence?
(Although the placing of the first of these 'Amen's is discussed in this question, the placing of the second one is not.)

The answer brought in the question I link is enough to explain why one of the first two amens is needed, but not both
